# Using colors in a selector xml

Tags: android, layout, coding-style

I want to set colors for clicking instead of images.  Doing so doesn't give any errors except for force-closing at runtime.  Is it even possible to do this or can selector only be used for images?

Code I'm trying below:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:background="#00C0FF" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:background="#0060FF" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:background="#00C0FF" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:background="#FFFFFF" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

```
<item>
     Defines a drawable to use during certain states, as described by its attributes. Must be a child of a <selector> element.

    android:drawable
        Drawable resource. **Required.** Reference to a drawable resource.
```

You can create a simple shape drawable to hold the color

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#33FF33"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: This is per definition a nifty solution to this problem. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it even possible to do this or can selector only be used for images?

No, this doesn't make any sense (to me at least). Without a 'drawable', how will it know exactly 'what' to set to state_focused and state_pressed?

Why not just create some single colour drawables (bitmaps for example) and provide those as the drawables for each item?

Comment: Well, the android:background tag can handle both. If using android:background="@drawable/image" it uses an image, if android:background="#FFFFFF" it uses the color. I see the effect that it has to be in the drawable folder though, meaning that a selector xml should have its own folder or that a drawable also could be a color. It makes no sense having to use images for simple colors on a device where resources are limited.

Comment: Fair comment. As I said I personally couldn't see how it could work without 'something' that could have 'focused' and 'pressed' states. Daren's answer finds a good middle ground between your approach and mine. In saying that though, small single colour images compress very nicely (using minimal resources) and can expand in a UI without degredation.

Comment: Also I guess that android "creates" an image from the shape just as if it would be an image - so as a resource it would be fairly the same. Just doing it the shape way seems better :-)